# On page refresh unique entry in database

Tags: php, html, session

On page load I make an entry in my database with the help of PHP. If I refresh a page then another entry is there in a database, I want to prevent this another entry.

How can it be done using session or cookies?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: This is not how it works. Show us your attempt. Nobody here can understand english language without code. Talk is cheap.

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to *write code for me*, while many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input, expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Logic is here

```
If(isset(*session*)){
       Do nothing;
}
else{
      1.Database insert;
      2.set *session* with expir time that you want (next time check in **if condition**)

}
```

You can also use cookies

Comment: Thanxs..But i am in little bit confusion that how to identify page reload or window close??(I am a new in all that )

Comment: @SonalNathavani There is no such way to prevent page reload with php. However you can just check before adding new entry to db if it already exists. For window close, there is a `onbeforeunload` event which fires when window close or page redirect happens.